# You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysqli

вот столкнулся с такой проблемой, в чем ошибка? код проверял не 1 раз

register.php

```
<div class="content">
    <form method="POST" action="/register" class="reg_form">
        <br><input type="text" name="login" > - Логин
        <br><input type="password" name="password" > -Пароль
        <br><input type="email" name="email" > - E-Mail
        <br><br><input type="submit" name="register" value="Регистрация">
    </form>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
            require_once 'assets/reg.php';
        }   
    ?>
</div>
```

reg.php

```
$_POST["login"] = FormChars($_POST["login"]);
$_POST["email"] = FormChars($_POST["email"]);
$_POST["password"] = GenPass(FormChars($_POST["password"]),$_POST['login']);


$login = $_POST["login"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

$pass = $_POST["password"];

if (!$login or !$email or !$pass) exit("<div class='alert'><div class='left_block'></div>Не все поля заполнены!</div>");


$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$login'"));

if ($row['username']) exit("<div class='alert'>Данное имя пользователя уже используется!</div>");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'"));

if ($row['email']) exit("<div class='alert'>Данный адрес электронной почты уже зарегистрирован!</div>");

mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO 'users' VALUES ('','$_POST[login]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[email]','NOW()'") or die(mysqli_error($CONNECT));

echo "<div class='success'>Поздравляем, вы успешно зарегистрировались!</div>";
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть показали полный текст ошибки....а не просто `error in your SQL syntax`. Нужно знать как она полностью звучит, на что указывает

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: `near` Где? ......

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id','username','password','email','regdate') VALUES ('','123','9131b6c45698d925' at line 1

Comment: @Bohdan Troianov, вам что думать религия не позволяет? Вы зачем кавычки везде и всюду пихаете? `id,username,password,email,regdate`

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO 'users' 
VALUES ('','$_POST[login]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[email]','NOW()'")
```

Учитывая предыдуший ответ, я бы сказал, что тут `'users'` взято в кавычки, когда правильнее так

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO users (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
VALUES ('','$_POST[login]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[email]','NOW()'")
```

Comment: желательно имена столбцов заключать в обратные кавычки... то есть в " ` "

Comment: при использовании такого кода ошибка не пропадает

Comment: @Bohdan Troianov, названия столбцов без кавычек!!!

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите синтаксис оператора INSERT
http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert.html
нужно указать имена полей куда вы пишете значения

Comment: Это не обязательный элемент оператора, поэтому он указывается в квадратных скобках. Используется когда вам нужно поменять порядок следования полей или указать их ограниченный набор.